# Sharepoint 2019 - Default site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, publishing-site, intranet, communication-site

We have a SP2013 on premise installation and plan to move towards SP2019 on premise installation.

What I am trying to establish is what is the default site in SP2019. Is it a Communication Site or is it a Publishing Site or Home Site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly it depends on your requirements. As hub sites will not be available in SP 2019, you may consider communication sites as a choice.

In the modern experience, Communication sites fulfill the same purpose as traditional publishing sites.

Reference links:

[Moving from Publishing sites to Communication sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/publishing-sites-classic-to-modern-experience)

[What is a SharePoint communication site?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-a-sharepoint-communication-site-94a33429-e580-45c3-a090-5512a8070732)

Comment: I am reading this sort of information - I have read both of the above docs. The only question I have is about SharePoint home pages - are they available as yet?  and if not - when will they be? Needing to establish how to approach our new site setup.

Comment: @garvon-77 I am not sure if i understand your question. Communication sites have their built-in homepage. Just like the pics you see in the article. You just need to add required contents to show.

Comment: Hi Jerry - I was referring to this blog - I have since read more and have discovered that is fundamentally a communication site. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/SharePoint-home-sites-a-landing-for-your-organization-on-the/ba-p/621933

Answer (score 1):

There is no default. It is whatever you wish to provision. Often times companies will use a Publishing site (pre-2019/SPO) or a Communication site (2019/SPO) as the root site of a Web Application.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I believe communication sites are the preferred way to go since SP have moved away from Hub sites?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like any default site. It is totally depend on you. You can choose which site template you want to use.

Please check below links for clarification on comm site vs team site and decide which one you want to use for your requirements.

- https://www.tatvasoft.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-sharepoint-modern-team-site-vs-communication-site/
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Communication-Site-vs-Team-Site/m-p/84148

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a default website. It is all up to you. You have the option of selecting a site template.

Please check the below links

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-user-profile-country-property/m-p/1393809/highlight/false#M41208